# How to create one combined measure of three databases

Tags: sql-server, database, measure

I have three tables of three different financial databases(of three companies) in my report in power bi. For every table I have one measure (summation of debit), and I need to have a summation of this three measures on a card. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create in dax a measure that sum the 3 other measure direclty in Power BI.

When you will apply filter on tables, you measure will get the filter from the source table.